# How does one operator pass on event stream to another operator?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Operator one can pass on event data to operator two, in a pipeline, through  GoLang channel, if implemented in GoLang. This helps avoid separation of concerns, amidst runtime failure.

Does flink operator pass on event to another operator through a direct method call or through some Queuing technique?

Answer (score 1):

> Does flink operator pass on event to another operator through a direct method call or through some Queuing technique?

That depends. Two or more operators in an operator chain (operators connected only by forward connections) pass events through direct method calls. Otherwise the messages are serialized and sent either via shared memory buffers (if the operators are in the same JVM) or via the network.

Comment: In what scenarios, messages are serialized? And sent via shared memory buffer

Comment: If the operators are not chained, then the messages are serialized. The serialized messages are sent via the network when the sender and recipient are in different JVMs, otherwise they use shared memory.